# Getting "Server unexpectedly closed network connection" after executing a remote command with Plink

Tags: ssh, command, putty, plink

I am using Plink to execute remote command:

When using remote command (text file) error occurs:

> FATAL ERROR: Server unexpectedly closed network connection

test.bat

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"  XX.XX.XX.XX -l userID -pw password   -m "D:\FindingLog\test.txt"
```

test.txt

```
cd log
```

---

When I remove `-m "D:\FindingLog\test.txt"` in batch file, it works (successful login)

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The SSH session closes (and Plink with it) as soon as the command finishes. Normally the "command" is shell. As you have overridden this default "command" and yet you seem to want to run the shell nevertheless, you have to explicitly execute the shell yourself:

```
cd log
/bin/bash
```

Also as use of `-m` switch implies a non-interactive terminal, you probably want to force an interactive terminal back using [`-t` switch](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-pty).

---

See also [How to prevent PuTTY shell from auto-exit after executing command from batch file in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27076891/850848)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As your comment, I changed .txt to .sh(written by vim) and added option -t. But It dosen't work.  This is the script in the batch file --------->  "C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"  XX.XX.XX.XX -l userID -pw password -m "D:\test.sh" -t -------- test.sh -------> cd log (also i tried writing /bin/bash and #!/bin/bash)

Comment: The extension does not matter. + *"It doesn't work"* doesn't work as problem description. Be more specific. + Also, from your comment, it's not clear to me, what did you try to put to `D:\test.sh`. Consider appending details of your new attempts to your question for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to plink 0.74 fixed this issue for me (from much older version 0.60).